# Codeigniter Model foreach return just single record

Tags: php, codeigniter

we are using following code in **Model**, we are passing one text string with different ids of album, exlode, convert it to array and we are passing array ids in foreach and foreach return as 10 to 20 different albums result, but when we call this function from Controller, its return just single 1 records, whats wrong in code?

```
public function get_footer_links($album_ids) {
    $album_ids = explode(',', $album_ids);
    foreach ($album_ids as $album_id) {

        $this->db->select('ci_albums.album_name, ci_albums.album_slug, ci_categories.cat_slug'); 
        $this->db->from('ci_albums');
        $this->db->join('ci_categories', 'ci_categories.cat_id = ci_albums.cat_id' , 'left');
        $this->db->where('album_id', $album_id);
       $results = $this->db->get()->result();
    }

    return $results;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($footer_links as $footer_links): foreach ($footer_links as $footer_link): ?>
       <a href="<?php echo site_url() . $footer_link->cat_slug .'/'. $footer_link->album_slug .'.html'; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo ucwords($footer_link->album_name); ?></a> | 
    <?php endforeach; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns just 1 result because at every cycle of the foreach you override the $result variable and so you miss all the result you get before.
You need to use an array instead of `$result` and the return to the controller that array.

For example:

```
$result_array[] = $this->db->get()->result()
```

and after the loop you need to return the array:

```
return $result_array
```

Comment: yeah, it works, but in view, we have got results in, array in nested 10 to 20 arrays, how we can get records from primary and nested arrays? we can use, foreach and nested foreach in view?

Comment: you can use the `foreach` or the `for` in the view: `for( $i=0; $i<count($result_array); $i++){ print_r($result_array[$i]); }`

Comment: please check my question view code, foreach under foreach work for me, but it look ugly

Comment: because multi arrays created in this function, when we assign this function results to view we need to put again all stuff in array, like, $this->data['footer_links'] = $this->frontend_m->get_footer_links($setting->footer_links); so in view, we have 1 primary array, footer_links and records array also nested in it..

Comment: try to print_r the $footer_links in your view, what you have?

Comment: array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[27]
          public 'album_name' => string '2 states' (length=8)

Answer (score 0):

In your code on each iteration $results is being replaced by the previous iteration of foreach loop, and that's why $results holds only one record.

```
public function get_footer_links($album_ids)
    {
        $album_ids = explode(',', $album_ids);
        $results = array();
        foreach ($album_ids as $album_id)
        {

            $this->db->select('ci_albums.album_name, ci_albums.album_slug, ci_categories.cat_slug');
            $this->db->from('ci_albums');
            $this->db->join('ci_categories', 'ci_categories.cat_id = ci_albums.cat_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where('album_id', $album_id);
            $result = $this->db->get()->result();
            array_push($results, $result);
        }

        return $results;
    }
```